# NumberFormatter in xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting

I have been struggling since last few hours. My code was working in xcode 10.XX. After I updated to xcode 11, the numberFormatter stopped working and now I connot get a number from a string value. The below code gives me 552 € in xcode 10 and nil in xcode 11. Can anyone help me recognize what the problem is?

```
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

    currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
    if let priceString = currencyFormatter.number(from: "552") {
        print(priceString) // Should Display 552 € in the German locale
    }
```

Comment: Wait. What are you trying to achieve? Converting a string to a number? Or vice versa? In your code it looks like you are mixing up those scenarios.

Comment: @AndréSlotta: I need a vice-versa. But probably if I get string to number working, the other side would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `NumberFormatter` with a `numberStyle` of `currency` to convert a string containing a regular number – "552" – which is not a currency string. That does not work.

You have to use the `decimal` style to convert the string to a number. Afterwards you can use the `currency` style to convert the number back to a string.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")

// string to number
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
if let n = formatter.number(from: "552") {
    print(n) // prints "552"

    // number to string (formatted as currency)
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let s = formatter.string(from: n) {
        print(s) // prints "552,00 €"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems to make good sense. But why does the above code work in xcode 10?

Comment: If it is the **exact** same code it should not work imho.

Comment: `print(priceString)` from your example code will **never** print "552 €" because `priceString` isn't a `String` but an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Probably you are correct. I might be using something else in the previous xcode version. Anyways thanks for the help.